# Localhost certificate safety

Tags: asp.net, .net, certificate

I've got an asp.net service that I want to run on localhost on each machine, is it safe to create the certificate with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust` or should I use another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes it is safe,** and recommended for development sites. The `--trust` option is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs) as:

> `-t|--trust`
>
> Trusts the certificate on the local machine.
>
> If this option isn't specified, the certificate is added to the certificate store but not to a trusted list.

So if you use it then it will take that certificate and pin it as trusted on this machine (it does not help for other machines).

This means that you can connect to the development site without insecurely ignoring certificate validation.

**Do not use this in a production scenario** where you are connecting multiple machines to a single server. This command only works on a single machine, so it's difficult to manage. It's much much better to buy a certificate from public CA or use a private CA to issue one.

Comment: Hello, my point is that this will be in production, I will need a localhost server on each machine, the macchines have a piece of hardware connected and the localhost WebAPI is a wrapper on the driver

Comment: That's probably OK then, although you could still add the certificate via Group Policy if you have a domain, rather than by command line.

Comment: A domain for localhost?

Comment: No I mean the machine you are installing this application on is joined to a AD domain. Then you can create a single `localhost` certificate, and pin it using Group Policy.